# How to include quotes in a string variable?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have tried the backslash and the double quotes.

Below is the class

whats the problem is i want the string variable prodpage to have `/apex/prod1` but the quotes are not included, but i want them included, i have tried `Prodpage = "'" + '/apex/prod1' + "'";`  and `Prodpage = '\'/apex/prod1\'';`

First one gives error:

> not recognizable in apex

The second one gives error :

> formula expression not correct

It compiles but it gives error in runtime.

```
public Class productslistpage{

    public list<inventory__c> prodlist{get; set;} 
    public string PID{get; set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
    public string usermode{get; set;}
    public String prodid {get; set;}
    public String prodpic {get; set;}
    public String prodpage {get; set;}  


public productslistpage(){
    prodlist = new list<inventory__c>();

    prodpic = 'testprod1';
    this.name = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name');
    this.usermode = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('usermode');
    prodlist = [Select prodpic__c,ButtonName__c,Name, Price__c, Stocks__c,productid__c from Inventory__c];
}     

         PageReference pg;

public pagereference prod1button(){

    for(inventory__c product : prodlist)  
      {
          if (product.productid__c == prodid){
              prodpage =  '/apex/' + product.buttonname__c;
          }
     } 


       pg = new PageReference(prodpage);  


      return pg;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape quotes in the url to redirect.

If you want to redirect to your prod1 page you juste have to use:

```
pg = new PageReference('apex/prod1');
```

Or:

```
return Page.prod1;
```

**Note for later:** If someday you need to escape quotes in a String variable, you can use the backslash: `String escapedQuotes = '\'myStringWithQuotes\'';`

Comment: the page redirection is dependent , it gets value from the if condition, prodpage variable will get populated in the if condition ,I just skipped that part and explicitly coded in the line in last. prodpage doesn't work because it doesn't include the quote in it.

Comment: I changed the code,and updated above, i used backslash,it compiles but it fails at run time displaying error "Formula Expression is required on the action attributes."

Comment: I really don't understand why you need escaped quotes in your url. It's not supposed to happen. Also, the error you mentioned doesn't look like it comes from the code related to your `productslistpage` class but from the `prod1` page.

Comment: ummm, give some time, let me look into it.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have updated, this is what i was trying to do , but error "rgument 1 cannot be null
Error is in expression '{!prod1button}' in page testcheckpage: Class.productslistpage.prod1button: line 37, column 1" is displayed.so I was just checking populating prodpage with prod1 to test,the code works fine when i explicitly state prodpage='apex/prod1' , but i dont want that, i want prodpage =  '/apex/' + product.buttonname__c; to work because i want it to direct to page in accordance with the product item clicked on.the buttonname__c changes for each product item.

Comment: Please post a new question with the whole code and a text which explains everthing.

Comment: ok, will do that.

Comment: oh i get it now, it was something else, thanks for the answer though, you were right, i didn't need to use escaped quotes.